# How to get ( random documents AND use $slice to limit elements of array ) using Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I want to get a random documents of posts AND at least 2 or 3 first comments of each post.
for first step I use below code for getting a random documents and it works perfectly but for the second step ( getting first 3 comments of each post I have problem. any suggestion?

`db.posts.aggregate([{$sample: {size: 5}}])`

this is my posts collection:

````
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e11f4bb73a901dfcb70712"),
    "username" : "user_001",
    "description" : "hello my friend",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e11ff0ae963901d89e13ee"),
            "username" : "user_1",
            "comment" : "this is first comment of this post"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e1220257f2e027542a7d06"),
            "username" : "user_2",
            "comment" : "this is second comment of this post"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e1256021f48f0ce43e39b3"),
            "username" : "user_3",
            "comment" : "this is a test comment"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e1259321f48f0ce43e39b7"),
            "username" : "user_4",
            "comment" : "test 4"
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e1290fe14b3a1584275210"),
    "username" : "user_002",
    "description" : "love is love",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e11ff0ae963901d89e13ea"),
            "username" : "user_5",
            "comment" : "this is first comment of this post"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e1220257f2e027542a7d0f"),
            "username" : "user_1",
            "comment" : "this is second comment of this post"
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e1290fe14b3a1584275212"),
    "username" : "user_003",
    "description" : "test post",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e11ff0ae963901d89e13aa"),
            "username" : "user_5",
            "comment" : "test comment"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e1220257f2e027542a7d0c"),
            "username" : "user_8",
            "comment" : "ha ha ha"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e1220257f2e027542a7d46"),
            "username" : "user_10",
            "comment" : "comment..."
        }
    ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get first 3 comments by adding slice query as follows.

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $sample: {size: 5}
    }, 
    {
        $project: {
            comments: {$slice: ["$comments", 3]}
        }
    } 
])
```

Please check this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) for more details.